# Remove mouseout after a given number of alerts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am an artist trying to learn programming for a new project/

I am trying to create a program where with a mouseout alert that is triggered only the first three time the function is called. Here is my code. at the moment, it is triggered three times:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="message">
   <input type="button" value="CLICK HERE" id="countButton" />

    <p style="color: white">The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 0;
      var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
      var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");



      button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;

        if (count <=3){
          button.onmouseout = function () {
            alert("        Come on... BACK TO WORK!");
          }
        }

        else if(count>3){
        document.body.innerHTML=""
        alert("FINALLY!!!");
}
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That s a shorter version of the program. You can see final result (minus the mouseout issue ) on the link below: http://www.esmeraldakosmatopoulos.com/blank#!/c1fam
Warning: it is pretty annoying... on purpose.

Please help me

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is the `else` part of the code. It reattaches a `mouseout` handler on every click on the button while `count <= 3`.

You need to move `button.onmouseout = {...}` out of the `onclick` handler, then into `else`put `button.onmouseout = null;`.

However, I'd suggest you to use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of event properties. To remove a listener you can use [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) This way you would have a better control over event handling.